# EnvironmentObject causes unrelated ObservedObject to reset

Tags: swiftui, observedobject, environmentobject

I am not quite sure I understand what is going on here as I am experimenting with an EnvironmentObject in SwiftUI.

I recreated my problem with a small example below, but to summarize: I have a `ContentView`, `ContentViewModel`, and a `StateController`. The `ContentView` holds a *TextField* that binds with the `ContentViewModel`. This works as expected. However, if I update a value in the `StateController` (which to me should be completely unrelated to the `ContentViewModel`) the text in the TextField is rest.

Can someone explain to me why this is happening, and how you could update a state on an EnvironmentObject without having SwiftUI redraw unrelated parts?

**App.swift**

```
@main
struct EnvironmentTestApp: App {

    @ObservedObject var stateController = StateController()

    var body: some Scene {
        WindowGroup {
            ContentView()
                .environmentObject(stateController)
        }
    }
}
```

**ContentView.swift**

```
struct ContentView: View {

    @ObservedObject private var viewModel = ContentViewModel()
    @EnvironmentObject private var stateController: StateController

    var body: some View {
        HStack {
            TextField("Username", text: $viewModel.username)
            Button("Update state") {
                stateController.validated = true
            }
        }

    }
}
```

**ContentViewModel.swift**

```
class ContentViewModel: ObservableObject {
    @Published var username = ""
}
```

**StateController.swift**

```
class StateController: ObservableObject {
    @Published var validated = false
}
```

Comment: try changing `@ObservedObject` to `@StaeObject`

Comment: There you go! After changing the ViewModel to a @StateObject it works! But I don't really understand why? Thanks a lot!

Comment: Watch Demystifying SwiftUI, `@ObservedObject` does not have the ability to preserve identify, `@StateObject` does, that is its purpose. https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/managing-model-data-in-your-app

Comment: Thank you, I will defiantly read up on this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Like lorem-ipsum pointed out, you should use @StateObject.

A good rule of thumb is to use `@StateObject` every time you init a viewModel, but use `@ObservedObject` when you are passing in a viewModel that has already been init.

Comment: rule of thumb or is there an actual documented reason?